# Is there any established database schema to store references?

Tags: reference-request, reference-managers, databases

I wonder whether there exists any well-established database schema(s) to store references.

For example, the Perl package [Bib2ML (aka. Bib2HTML)](http://get-software.net/biblio/bibtex/utils/bib2ml/doc/index.html) contains a `bib2sql` tool that generates a SQL database from a BibTeX database, with the following schema:

[image]

If there is no well-established schema, I am still interested to know about alternatives. One can assume the data it contains can be extracted from the paper or the BibTeX (i.e. no need to be able to store information coming from other sources, and the focus is on the reference, not the paper's content).

Comment: What do you want to do? Why is a plain .bib file not enough?

Comment: @Davidmh A SQL database to make it easier to query a set of references.

Comment: I meant what do you want to do with that database, as opposed to plain bib?

Comment: @Davidmh query it

Answer (score 3):

If you would consider an approach of storing bibliographic information in *XML format*, either directly (as XML files), or indirectly (via serialization or XML-to-RelationalDB conversion), you might find the following resources of interest (some of the resources are *general* and/or *database-focused*):

- [Metadata Object Description Schema (MODS)](http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods) by *The Library of Congress* (USA);
- [Standards at The Library of Congress](http://www.loc.gov/standards) page lists a host of relevant information;
- [Apache OpenOffice bibliographic implementation](https://www.openoffice.org/bibliographic/implementation.html) and [bibliographic database information](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Bibliographic/Database);
- development documentation for any other *open source bibliography management software* (JabRef, Zotero, etc.); for more information, see [this list](https://www.openhub.net/tags?names=bibliography);
- [Dublin Core Metadata Initiative (DCMI)](http://dublincore.org);
- [List of citation standards](http://dublincore.org/groups/citation/citstds.html), which might be used to store bibliographic metadata (by DCMI);
- Finally, for the *NoSQL* way of doing things, consider using [BibJSON schema](http://okfnlabs.org/bibjson) and, for the *linked data* emphasis, consider using [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org) (also see [this relevant article](http://journal.code4lib.org/articles/4893)).

Answer (score 2):

I expect most reference management software uses some sort of database system to store the local data in an easily accessible way.

In particular I know that [Mendeley stores the local database using SQlite](http://support.mendeley.com/customer/en/portal/articles/227951-how-do-i-locate-mendeley-desktop-database-files-on-my-computer-), although I doubt there is any common standard across different software.